# How to request certain page elements not be indexed

Tags: html, search-engine

Essentially I would like to specify an element to be ignored by search engines. If I reference pornography from an academic standpoint, I don't want Google to list my site under porn searches, for instance, but would like it to index the rest of the page.

Is this possible? I'm sure I have come across a method of including meta data into one's html to achieve this.

I have tried to find this on the web, but have been unsuccessful. 
I can't make sense of [this page](http://microformats.org/wiki/robots-exclusion), since I don't know if because it's a draft specification it is not recognised by crawl bots.

Answer (score 1):

Using the robots.txt File in the root directory of your website.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /myreference_dir/
Disallow: /myreference_dir/myarticle.html
```

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard)

Comment: I wish to ignore HTML elements such as <div>, not entire html documents.

Comment: Google already processes all the HTML on the page. Why would asking it to exclude some be CPU intensive?